# Android viewpagerindicator XML error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerIndicatorStyle'

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, viewpagerindicator

The problem is these 6 lines in layout XML. If I remove these 6 lines, Eclipse compiles but runs with com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator inflation error. In the project property android library reference section, there is red-cross in front of referenced viewpagerindicator library project and there is '?' for project name. Is this the cause? How to turn red-cross into green-checker?

```
        app:footerColor="#FFAA2222"
        app:footerLineHeight="4dp"
        app:footerIndicatorHeight="22dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
        app:selectedColor="#FF000000"
        app:selectedBold="true"
```

Here is the error message in Eclipse XML editor:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerIndicatorStyle' in package    'com.example.testtab'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerColor' in package 'com.example.testtab'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'selectedBold' in package 'com.example.testtab'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'selectedColor' in package 'com.example.testtab'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerIndicatorHeight' in package       'com.example.testtab'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerLineHeight' in package    'com.example.testtab'

Here is the XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:background="#18FF0000"
        android:textColor="#AA000000"
        app:footerColor="#FFAA2222"
        app:footerLineHeight="4dp"
        app:footerIndicatorHeight="22dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
        app:selectedColor="#FF000000"
        app:selectedBold="true"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the project and the library project reside in different drive(C: and D: respectively) on Windows 7. The problem solved by moving them into the same drive. This is a bug. ADT version 22.05, Eclipse version Juno Release 2. Target API 18.